# Extracting all values from a GLib GTree

Tags: c, glib

I've built a GLib `GTree` which contains key/value pairs where the key is a character (e.g. 'a') and the value is the frequency by which that character appears in a string. For example, if the string was 'aaa' then the only element in the tree would be: 'a' => 3.

What I want to do is iterate over the tree and keep a count of the number of characters with a given frequency, i.e. where the value of the key/value pair matches.

The pseudocode would be something like:

```
frequency_count = 0
while (current_element = get_next_element)
  if (current_element->value == desired_frequency)
    frequency_count = frequency_count + 1
```

Is there a way to do this with a `GTree`? The only function I can find is `g_tree_foreach()`, but that requires me to pass a callback function that returns `TRUE` to stop traversing the tree, and I don't want to stop traversal until I've visited every element. Am I supposed to use the `gpointer user_data` parameter of the callback function to pass in the frequency count and desired frequency values?

Comment: I disagree with your comments "that requires me to pass a callback function that returns TRUE to stop traversing the tree". It is not the return value of the callback function that stops the tree traversal. It's simply an optimization thing that if the callback returns True, stop immediately. If you have doubts, try with a callback function that prints true in a log and never returns true. Simple test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I supposed to use the `gpointer user_data` parameter of the callback function to pass in the frequency count and desired frequency values?

Yes.

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
  guint desired_frequency;
  guint n_matches;
} MatchData;

static gboolean
n_nodes_matching_frequency_cb (gpointer key,
                               gpointer value,
                               gpointer user_data)
{
  MyTreeElement *element = value;
  MatchData *data = user_data;

  if (element->value == data->desired_frequency)
    data->n_matches++;

  return FALSE;
}

guint
n_nodes_matching_frequency (GTree *tree,
                            guint  desired_frequency)
{
  MatchData data = { desired_frequency, 0 };
  g_tree_foreach (tree, n_nodes_matching_frequency_cb, &data);
  return data.n_matches; 
}
```